# HP Pavilion dv7 with Vista, trying to install Ubuntu 11.04. Gets stuck at Busybox, prompts me for (initramfs)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, hp-pavilion

I have a brand new MacBook Pro waiting on the sidelines but I don't feel it is right to "waste" this perfectly workable HP Pavilion dv7 computer even though it runs the plague that is Vista. I felt like experimenting with Linux and so I am totally okay with reformatting my existing hard drive and installing a new OS (In this case, Ubuntu 11.04).
Some things to note: my CD drive does not work, but both USB drives do work.

Anyways I burned the iso for 11.04 Ubuntu onto a 4gb USB key and finally figured out how to change the BIOS in order to boot from USB. I booted from USB and the Ubuntu menu came up so I clicked on "install on existing hard drive" (not exact wording, but whatever).

It went through and stopped at "BusyBox v.1.xx.xx" and eventually I was prompted (initramfs) with a blinking cursor and I have no idea what's going on. I am generally good at troubleshooting and other forums I have asked have given me answers like "oh don't mess with linux you have no idea what you're doing." which I feel is somewhat unconstructive. I kind of know what's going on and would really like to install this OS. feel free to ask me other questions if you need some more specificity.

I really appreciate any help. Thanks a mill.

Also; I kind of felt something was going horribly wrong because there was many lines of code that said "xx not found," "directory not found,"and is this attributable to the fact that its rebuilding the hard drive from scratch? Is it automatically reformatting?

Answer (score 0):

What program did you use to burn the ISO to your thumb drive? I've seen this happen on improperly created thumb drives. I would recommend using UNETBootIN

http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks but the same problem occurred.

Comment: I used the one recommended on the Ubuntu site.